# Set the transparency color when exporting SVGs to Bitmap using TSVGIconImage

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

I use [TSVGImageIcon](https://github.com/EtheaDev/SVGIconImageList) to read SVG vector images, and I have created this routine to save an image as a bitmap of a certain size :

```
function SVG2Bitmap(Imatge: TBytes; x, y: integer): TBytes;
var SVG: TSVGIconImage;
    Stream: TBytesStream;
    Bitmap: TBitmap;
    Resultat: TBytesStream;
    Form: TForm;
begin
  try
    SVG := nil;
    Form := nil;
    Stream := nil;
    Bitmap := nil;
    Resultat := nil;
    Stream := TBytesStream.Create(Imatge);
    Stream.Position := 0;
    Form := TForm.Create(nil);  // The SVGIconImage raises an error if not inside a Form
    SVG := TSVGIconImage.Create(Form);
    SVG.Parent := Form;
    SVG.Stretch := True;
    SVG.Proportional := True;
    SVG.LoadFromStream(Stream);
    SVG.Width := x;
    SVG.Height := y;
    Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
    Bitmap.SetSize(x, y);
    SVG.PaintTo(Bitmap.Canvas, 0, 0); 
    Resultat := TBytesStream.Create;
    Bitmap.SaveToStream(Resultat);
    Result := Resultat.Bytes;
  finally
    if Assigned(SVG) then try SVG.Free except end;
    if Assigned(Form) then try Form.Free except end;
    if Assigned(Bitmap) then try Bitmap.Free except end;
    if Assigned(Stream) then try Stream.Free except end;
    if Assigned(Resultat) then try Resultat.Free except end;
  end;
end;
```

It works very well, but it fills the transparent zones as grey and I would like them as white. Can you recommend of a way to export SVGs to bitmap while setting the transparency color or should I just loop through the bitmap changing the grey pixels to white ?.

Thank you.

Comment: Since `X.Free` does `if Assigned(X) then X.Destroy`, your `if Assigned(X) then X.Free` does `if Assigned(X) then if Assigned(X) then X.Destroy`. Do you see the redundancy?

Comment: Thanks @AndreasRejbrand, I didn't know that x.Free checks if X is Assigned. I have written a lot of unnecessary checks :-).

Comment: I'm not sure but I'm guessing that `SVG.PaintTo` only renders the nontransparent portions of the SVG image. If so then filling your bitmap with desired color before painting the SVG will solve your problem.

Comment: I tried that @SilverWarior but it still switches the transparent zones to grey.

Comment: Is it `.SetFixedColor()`?

Comment: @AmigoJack where do I find this method ?, I don't see it on the SVGIconImage or the Bitmap/Canvas.

Comment: Try changing the bitmap's `Canvas.Brush.Color`, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/EtheaDev/SVGIconImageList/issues/111#issuecomment-692869387).

Comment: @SilverWarior, Olivier: But surely the `TBitmap`'s default colour isn't grey?

Comment: @Olivier, No, adding Bitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite; before the SVG.PaintTo(Bitmap.Canvas, 0, 0); didn't solve the problem. I have simply added a loop through the bitmap changing pixels with 15790320 color to clWhite, and it works well for me (my images are maps with just black lines), although it would be nice to have a proper solution.

Comment: @MarcGuillot: `Bitmap := TBitmap.Create; Bitmap.SetSize(x, y); Bitmap.Canvas.Color := clWhite; Bitmap.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, x, y)); SVG.PaintTo(Bitmap.Canvas, 0, 0);` is the suggestion. But as I indicated above, I don't think it will work since the default colour of a bitmap isn't grey.

Comment: Then you should try AmigoJack's suggestion: `TSVGIconImage` does have a `FixedColor` property (the setter is private).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: On a new TBitmap instance if you set the Bitmap.Canvas.Color before Bitmap.SetSize there is no need to use FillRect.

Comment: @Olivier FixedColor turns out to change the color of the black lines that form my maps, not the background. But I've found that SVGIconImage uses as background color the color of its container, so setting Form.Color to clWhite solves the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @AmigoJack FixedColor turns out to change the color of the black lines that form my maps, not the background. But I've found that SVGIconImage uses as background color the color of its container, so setting Form.Color to clWhite solves the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the SVGIconImage uses the color of the parent container as the transparency color. So changing that Form.Color to my chosen TransparencyColor does the trick.

```
function SVG_2_Bitmap(ImageSVG: TBytes; x, y: integer; TransparencyColor: TColor = clWhite): TBytes;
var SVG: TSVGIconImage;
    Stream, Resultat: TBytesStream;
    Bitmap: TBitmap;
    Form: TForm;
begin
  SVG := nil;
  Form := nil;
  Stream := nil;
  Bitmap := nil;
  Resultat := nil;
  try
    Stream := TBytesStream.Create(ImageSVG);
    Form := TForm.Create(nil);
    Form.Color := TransparencyColor;
    SVG := TSVGIconImage.Create(Form);
    SVG.Parent := Form;
    SVG.Proportional := True;
    SVG.LoadFromStream(Stream);
    SVG.Width := x;
    SVG.Height := y;
    Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
    Bitmap.SetSize(x, y);
    SVG.PaintTo(Bitmap.Canvas, 0, 0);
    Resultat := TBytesStream.Create;
    Bitmap.SaveToStream(Resultat);
    Result := Resultat.Bytes;
  finally
    try SVG.Free except end;
    try Form.Free except end;
    try Bitmap.Free except end;
    try Stream.Free except end;
    try Resultat.Free except end;
  end;
end;
```

Thanks for all your suggestions.